# Time Complexity of the TreeMap.subMap().clear()

Tags: java, treemap

What is the time complexity of the following code ?

```
TreeMap<Integer, Integer> tree = new TreeMap<>();// assume the treeMap contains N number of keys
NavigableMap<Integer, Integer> subMap = tree.subMap(left, true, right, true);// assume the subMap contains M number of keys
subMap.clear()// what will be the expected time complexity of this line ?
```

To clear K keys it would take `O(M log N)` ?
To remove Keys one by one it would definitely take `O(M log N)`. But I'm not sure as the removed keys are in a range would it take `O(M)` ?

Comment: It's implementation-dependent, but I would expect the time complexity of any reasonable mutable map's clear implementation to be O(1). Internally, it holds a reference to some data structure (e.g. an array or something). It can just throw away the reference to that data structure and instantiate a new empty one. That should not depend on the number of existing elements.

Comment: To remove an entire subtree, you **could** just clear one link.  But on the other hand, depending on what kind of tree it is, some rebalancing might be needed.  Have you looked at the source code?

Comment: @Michael I'd expect it to be a bit more than constant: something like `O(lg N)`, because it has to find the start and end subtrees.

Comment: @AndyTurner Oh, is it because subMap creates a view onto the original map? I'd presumed it was a copy. So clearing it is not strictly deleting everything (which should always be O(1)) but rather deleting whatever portion the view points to?

Comment: @Michael even if it was a copy, it would still need to find the start and end of the range to copy.

Comment: @Michael For HashMap kind of implementation it could be possible to be done in O(1). But TreeMap is a Balanced Tree. Hence i  doubted it could take more than O(1). Another reason why i doubted O(lg N) is that usually balanced trees are implemented keeping in mind that before and executing a method the map remains balanced. But removing a set of numbers from it could cost a little more. Hence the doubt.

Comment: @AndyTurner Right, but they asked about the complexity of `clear` specifically, not the complexity of the whole thing. So the complexity of the copy is not relevant. If it's a copy, the new map has some reference to a root node, and could just replace that with a new empty root node.

Comment: @Michael yes i'm concerned about the complexity of clear only. subMap just creates a new AscendingSubMap with boundaries set. So we can assume O(1) for that.

Comment: It looks to me that the complexity of the clear is O(M). `subMap` creates an `AscendingSubMap`, which gets its `clear` method from `AbstractMap`. `AbstractMap::clear` simply calls `entrySet().clear()`, which in this case is `AbstractCollection::clear`, which simply iterates through all the elements (so O(M)) and calls remove on each one of them.

Comment: @Michael Wouldn't it take O(M log N) as removing a key from the treeMap takes O(log N). so the total complexity would come around O (M log N) ?

Comment: @VeeraKumar You might be right but it's hard to tell. I think that's certainly the *worst* it could be, but it might be better than that. In order to remove an entry "normally" by `TreeMap::remove`, it needs to traverse the tree to find the entry before removing it. I think in the subMap case, it already has the entry so it doesn't need to traverse the tree first.

Comment: @Michael I'm also not sure about it. That's the reason I came here to know from others who have more knowledge regarding TreeMap.

Comment: `AscendingSubMap#clear` uses `AbstractCollection#clear`, i.e. it repeatedly calls `iterator#next` and `iterator#remove`. If `next` and `remove` are `O(1)` then this is `O((log n) + m)` (since it first has to find the starting key of the submap). That's the best case. I'm finding it quite difficult to confirm what the time complexity of `next` and `remove` are in this instance though ‍♂️